# Python - defining string split delimiter?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

How could I define string delimiter for splitting in most efficient way? I mean to not need to use many if's etc?

I have strings that need to be splited strictly into two element lists. The problem is those strings have different symbols by which I can split them. For example:

`'Hello: test1'`. This one has split delimiter `': '`. The other example would be:
`'Hello - test1'`. So this one would be `' - '`. Also split delimiter could be `' -'` or `'- '`. So if I know all variations of delimiters, how could I define them most efficiently?

First I did something like this:

```
strings = ['Hello - test', 'Hello- test', 'Hello -test']
for s in strings:
    delim = ' - '
    if len(s.split('- ', 1)) == 2:
        delim = '- '
    elif len(s.split(' -', 1)) == 2:
        delim = ' -'
    print s.split(delim, 1)[1])
```

But then I got new strings that had another unexpected delimiters. So doing this way I should add even more ifs to check other delimiters like `': '`. But then I wondered if there is some better way to define them (there is not problem if I should need to include new delimiters in some kind of list if I would need to later on). Maybe regex would help or some other tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the delimiters inside `re.split` function like below using logical OR `|` operator.

```
re.split(r': | - | -|- ', string)
```

Add `maxsplit=1`, if you want to do an one time split.

```
re.split(r': | - | -|- ', string, maxsplit=1)
```

Comment: This seems to be best way to define as you can define explicitly what delimiter is.

Comment: sorry, i don't know what you mean.

Comment: You could also update your answer, adding `maxsplit=1` as I asked how to split into two element lists. So after first split, it should not split that string anymore. And with that comment I meant, using other answers, delimiter can become for example `:-` even if you don't want that and then it splits wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) function of the re module

```
>>> strings = ['Hello1 - test1', 'Hello2- test2', 'Hello3 -test3', 'Hello4 :test4', 'Hello5 : test5']
>>> for s in strings:
...   re.split(" *[:-] *",s)
...
['Hello1', 'test1']
['Hello2', 'test2']
['Hello3', 'test3']
['Hello4', 'test4']
['Hello5', 'test5']
```

Where between `[]` you put all the possible delimiters. The `*` indicates that some spaces can be put before or after.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s*[:-]\s*
```

You can split by this.Use `re.split(r"\s*[:-]\s*",string)`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/14

You should use this if you can have delimiters like `-` or `-` or `-`.wherein you have can have multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best way, but if you want to avoid using `re` for some (or no) reason, this is what I would do:

```
>>> strings = ['Hello - test', 'Hello- test', 'Hello -test', 'Hello : test']
>>> delims = [':', '-']  # all possible delimiters; don't worry about spaces.
>>>
>>> for string in strings:
...     delim = next((d for d in delims if d in string), None) # finds the first delimiter in delims that's present in the string (if there is one)
...     if not delim:
...         continue  # No delimiter! (I don't know how you want to handle this possibility; this code will simply skip the string all together.)
...     print [s.strip() for s in string.split(delim, 1)]  # assuming you want them in list form.
['Hello', 'test']
['Hello', 'test']
['Hello', 'test']
['Hello', 'test']
```

This uses Python's native `.split()` to break the string at the delimiter, and then `.strip()` to trim the white space off the results, if there is any. I've used `next` to find the appropriate delimiter, but there are plenty of things you can swap that out with (especially if you like `for` blocks).

If you're certain that each string will contain at least one of the delimiters (preferably *exactly* one), then you can shave it down to this:

```
 ## with strings and delims defined...
>>> for string in strings:
...     delim = next(d for d in delims if d in string) # raises StopIteration at this line if there is no delimiter in the string.
...     print [s.strip() for s in string.split(delim, 1)]
```

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it uses fewer `if` blocks, and you won't have to import anything to do it.

Comment: If you use the first `for` block example, and you somehow are called upon to use zero as a delimiter, make sure you use string `'0'` and not integer `0`, since the integer is Falsey and `if not delim:` will run if delim == 0.
You may also want to change `if not delim:` to `if delim is None:` (or whatever you have `next`'s default set to) instead; a safer choice on the whole.